Why am i unable to deploy website on Git Hub?
I have been trying to deploy my code, but I keep getting an error 404 message. It says it's live, but when I click the link, it gives me an error 404 message.
I have changed the source to root.
I have even tried adding index.html to the GitHub link still my deployed code is giving me an error 404 message
I have also watched different videos on this yet none seems to solve my problem
Screenshot of workflow


Can you send a link to your repository? Or post your folder structure here? Did you build your site using Jekyll or is it just a static index.html file you're trying to publish?
Also have you hit "save" in the Branch section of your settings? The description says it's still being built from the "/docs" folder

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
